# libtk8.5 package on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I want to install a software called [ProB](https://www3.hhu.de/stups/prob/index.php/Download). I downloaded the Tarball and executed the StartProB.sh script. But unfortunately, it is required to have libtk8.5 on my machine. I tried to `sudo apt-get install -y libtk8.5` But it says

```
E: Unable to locate package libtk8.5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libtk8.5'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libtk8.5'
```

Is there a way to install lib8.5 for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: libtk8.5 was dropped after 18.04. libtk8.6, however, is in Ubuntu 20.04. I suppose you can download the 18.04 package. It might work, it might not.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. It says `package has unmet dependencies`

Comment: Well, that falls under "might not". Seems the software that you want to install is not compatible with 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe'`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install libtk8.5`

If this does not work reply and I'll try to fix it.

Best Regards And Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response. But when I tried adding the repository I get the following error `Error: need a single repository as argument`

Comment: try this `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/ bionic main'`

Comment: I added this repo successfully. But still getting the error of `E: Unable to locate package libk8-5`

Comment: Thats the issue their. Its not `libk8-5` its `libk8.5` that is my fault.

Comment: It still gives me the error `E: Unable to locate package libtk8.5`

Comment: strange... I'll keep looking on this issue.

Comment: could you send me the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` please?

Comment: Try the new solution.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much I was able to add libtk8.5 and the software which I wanted to install was successfully installed.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad I could help.